# Query using up all temp disc space - but only on one server

Tags: mysql

I've run into a strange situation where a query uses up all available disc space on one server (and then crashes, when there is no space left), but not on the other, and I'm not sure how to correct this situation.

On the OLD server, running MySQL **5.5.55**, the query uses up about 8 GB of disc space. It returns results after about 10 minutes.

On the NEW server, running MySQL **5.7.25**, the query used 15 GB and then ran out of disc space and terminated. A co-worker said that when there was more disc space available a little while ago, they observed the query using up closer to 30 GB before running out of space.

The data is the same on both servers.

The query is:

```sql
SELECT distinct subq1.duplicate_count, subq1.identifier, subq1.ReferenceEntity_DB_IDs, subq1._class AS object_type, subq1._displayName as display_name, subq1.combined_identifier, ReferenceDatabase_2_name.name as ref_db_name, subq1.species_db_id, subq1.species_name  
from ( 
    select count(ReferenceEntity.DB_ID) as duplicate_count, ReferenceEntity.identifier, group_concat(ReferenceEntity.db_id) as ReferenceEntity_DB_IDs, ReferenceEntity.referenceDatabase, DatabaseObject._class, DatabaseObject._displayName, subq.combined_identifier, subq.species_db_id, subq.species_name 
    from ReferenceEntity  
    inner join DatabaseObject on DatabaseObject.db_id = ReferenceEntity.db_id 
    inner join (select ReferenceEntity.*, concat(coalesce(ReferenceEntity.identifier,'NULL'),';', coalesce(DatabaseObject._displayName,'NULL')) as combined_identifier, species_subq.db_id AS species_db_id, species_subq.name AS species_name 
                from ReferenceEntity 
                inner join DatabaseObject on ReferenceEntity.db_id = DatabaseObject.db_id 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN ReferenceSequence ON ReferenceEntity.DB_ID = ReferenceSequence.DB_ID 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Species.DB_ID, Taxon_2_name.name 
                                   FROM Species  
                                   INNER JOIN Taxon_2_name ON (Taxon_2_name.DB_ID = Species.DB_ID AND Taxon_2_name.name_rank = 0)) AS species_subq 
               ON ReferenceSequence.species = species_subq.DB_ID 
                where ReferenceEntity.identifier is not null) as subq on subq.db_id = ReferenceEntity.db_id 
    group by subq.combined_identifier, ReferenceEntity.identifier, referenceDatabase, _class, _displayName, subq.species_db_id, subq.species_name 
    having count(ReferenceEntity.db_id) > 1) as subq1 
inner join ReferenceDatabase_2_name on ReferenceDatabase_2_name.DB_ID = subq1.referenceDatabase 
where ReferenceDatabase_2_name.name_rank = 0 
order by duplicate_count, ReferenceDatabase_2_name.name, identifier;
```

The query plan from the NEW server (where the query fails) looks like this:

```
+----+-------------+--------------------------+------------+--------+--------------------+-------------+---------+--------------------------------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                    | partitions | type   | possible_keys      | key         | key_len | ref                            | rows   | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+--------------------------+------------+--------+--------------------+-------------+---------+--------------------------------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | ReferenceDatabase_2_name | NULL       | ALL    | DB_ID              | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                           |    292 |    10.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>               | NULL       | ref    | <auto_key0>        | <auto_key0> | 5       | ReferenceDatabase_2_name.DB_ID |   2526 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
|  2 | DERIVED     | ReferenceEntity          | NULL       | ALL    | PRIMARY            | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                           | 737849 |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort              |
|  2 | DERIVED     | DatabaseObject           | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY            | PRIMARY     | 4       | ReferenceEntity.DB_ID          |      1 |   100.00 | Using index condition                        |
|  2 | DERIVED     | ReferenceEntity          | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,identifier | PRIMARY     | 4       | ReferenceEntity.DB_ID          |      1 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
|  2 | DERIVED     | ReferenceSequence        | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY            | PRIMARY     | 4       | ReferenceEntity.DB_ID          |      1 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
|  2 | DERIVED     | Species                  | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY            | PRIMARY     | 4       | ReferenceSequence.species      |      1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  2 | DERIVED     | Taxon_2_name             | NULL       | ref    | DB_ID              | DB_ID       | 5       | ReferenceSequence.species      |      1 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
|  2 | DERIVED     | DatabaseObject           | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY            | PRIMARY     | 4       | ReferenceEntity.DB_ID          |      1 |   100.00 | Using index condition                        |
+----+-------------+--------------------------+------------+--------+--------------------+-------------+---------+--------------------------------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

The query plan from the OLD server (where the query succeeds) is *different*, and it looks like this:

```
+----+-------------+--------------------------+--------+--------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                    | type   | possible_keys      | key     | key_len | ref                                    | rows   | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+--------------------------+--------+--------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>               | ALL    | NULL               | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                   |   4169 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | ReferenceDatabase_2_name | ref    | DB_ID              | DB_ID   | 5       | subq1.referenceDatabase                |      2 | Using where                     |
|  2 | DERIVED     | <derived3>               | ALL    | NULL               | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                   | 737849 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | ReferenceEntity          | eq_ref | PRIMARY            | PRIMARY | 4       | subq.DB_ID                             |      1 |                                 |
|  2 | DERIVED     | DatabaseObject           | eq_ref | PRIMARY            | PRIMARY | 4       | test_database_XX.ReferenceEntity.DB_ID |      1 | Using where                     |
|  3 | DERIVED     | ReferenceEntity          | ALL    | PRIMARY,identifier | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                   | 737849 | Using where                     |
|  3 | DERIVED     | ReferenceSequence        | eq_ref | PRIMARY            | PRIMARY | 4       | test_database_XX.ReferenceEntity.DB_ID |      1 |                                 |
|  3 | DERIVED     | <derived4>               | ALL    | NULL               | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                   |     79 |                                 |
|  3 | DERIVED     | DatabaseObject           | eq_ref | PRIMARY            | PRIMARY | 4       | test_database_XX.ReferenceEntity.DB_ID |      1 | Using where                     |
|  4 | DERIVED     | Species                  | index  | PRIMARY            | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL                                   |     79 | Using index                     |
|  4 | DERIVED     | Taxon_2_name             | ref    | DB_ID              | DB_ID   | 5       | test_database_XX.Species.DB_ID         |      1 | Using where                     |
+----+-------------+--------------------------+--------+--------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
```

My guess is that there is some significant difference in how these two instances of MySQL are configured, but I'm not sure. the MySQL 5.7.25 server was set up with a config split into several files, and since it's not the same version, I'm not sure how to properly compare.

Does anyone have any suggestions for debugging this issue? Maybe in terms of which variables to compare first?

---

**Edit:**

Global variables from NEW server:
https://pastebin.com/EacpyyAb

Global variables from OLD server:
https://pastebin.com/uSj7bEbt

Global status from NEW server:
https://pastebin.com/CD0g3qSb

Global status from OLD server:
https://pastebin.com/ETnTbKA1

Indicies, OLD server:

```
Table   Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name Collation   Cardinality Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment Index_comment
ReferenceDatabase_2_name    1   DB_ID   1   DB_ID   A   146 NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
ReferenceDatabase_2_name    1   name    1   name    A   97  10  NULL    YES BTREE       

Table   Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name Collation   Cardinality Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment Index_comment
ReferenceEntity 0   PRIMARY 1   DB_ID   A   737849  NULL    NULL        BTREE       
ReferenceEntity 1   referenceDatabase   1   referenceDatabase   A   90  NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
ReferenceEntity 1   identifier  1   identifier  A   245949  10  NULL    YES BTREE       

Table   Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name Collation   Cardinality Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment Index_comment
DatabaseObject  0   PRIMARY 1   DB_ID   A   2439461 NULL    NULL        BTREE       
DatabaseObject  1   _class  1   _class  A   65  NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
DatabaseObject  1   _timestamp  1   _timestamp  A   45175   NULL    NULL        BTREE       
DatabaseObject  1   created 1   created A   187650  NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
DatabaseObject  1   _displayName    1   _displayName    A   304932  10  NULL    YES BTREE       
DatabaseObject  1   stableIdentifier    1   stableIdentifier    A   2439461 NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       

Table   Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name Collation   Cardinality Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment Index_comment
ReferenceSequence   0   PRIMARY 1   DB_ID   A   735705  NULL    NULL        BTREE       
ReferenceSequence   1   species 1   species A   52  NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
ReferenceSequence   1   sequenceLength  1   sequenceLength  A   735705  NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
ReferenceSequence   1   isSequenceChanged   1   isSequenceChanged   A   735705  10  NULL    YES BTREE       
ReferenceSequence   1   checksum    1   checksum    A   735705  10  NULL    YES BTREE       

Table   Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name Collation   Cardinality Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment Index_comment
Species 0   PRIMARY 1   DB_ID   A   79  NULL    NULL        BTREE       
Species 1   abbreviation    1   abbreviation    A   79  10  NULL    YES BTREE       

Table   Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name Collation   Cardinality Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment Index_comment
Taxon_2_name    1   DB_ID   1   DB_ID   A   551 NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
Taxon_2_name    1   name    1   name    A   551 NULL    NULL    YES BTREE
```

NEW Server:

```
Table   Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name Collation   Cardinality Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment Index_comment
ReferenceDatabase_2_name    1   DB_ID   1   DB_ID   A   146 NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
ReferenceDatabase_2_name    1   name    1   name    A   97  10  NULL    YES BTREE       

Table   Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name Collation   Cardinality Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment Index_comment
ReferenceEntity 0   PRIMARY 1   DB_ID   A   737849  NULL    NULL        BTREE       
ReferenceEntity 1   referenceDatabase   1   referenceDatabase   A   90  NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
ReferenceEntity 1   identifier  1   identifier  A   245950  10  NULL    YES BTREE       

Table   Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name Collation   Cardinality Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment Index_comment
DatabaseObject  0   PRIMARY 1   DB_ID   A   2439461 NULL    NULL        BTREE       
DatabaseObject  1   _class  1   _class  A   65  NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
DatabaseObject  1   _timestamp  1   _timestamp  A   45175   NULL    NULL        BTREE       
DatabaseObject  1   created 1   created A   187651  NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
DatabaseObject  1   _displayName    1   _displayName    A   304933  10  NULL    YES BTREE       
DatabaseObject  1   stableIdentifier    1   stableIdentifier    A   2439461 NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       

Table   Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name Collation   Cardinality Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment Index_comment
ReferenceSequence   0   PRIMARY 1   DB_ID   A   735705  NULL    NULL        BTREE       
ReferenceSequence   1   species 1   species A   52  NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
ReferenceSequence   1   sequenceLength  1   sequenceLength  A   735705  NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
ReferenceSequence   1   isSequenceChanged   1   isSequenceChanged   A   735705  10  NULL    YES BTREE       
ReferenceSequence   1   checksum    1   checksum    A   735705  10  NULL    YES BTREE       

Table   Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name Collation   Cardinality Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment Index_comment
Species 0   PRIMARY 1   DB_ID   A   79  NULL    NULL        BTREE       
Species 1   abbreviation    1   abbreviation    A   79  10  NULL    YES BTREE       

Table   Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name Collation   Cardinality Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment Index_comment
Taxon_2_name    1   DB_ID   1   DB_ID   A   551 NULL    NULL    YES BTREE       
Taxon_2_name    1   name    1   name    A   551 NULL    NULL    YES BTREE
```

The NEW server doesn't log the error. The only message that it emits is `ERROR 3 (HY000): Error writing file '/tmp/MYIZQlbr' (Errcode: 28 - No space left on device)` I am not sure I have permission to change the error logging settings...

SHOW CREATE TABLE from OLD server:

```
Table   Create Table
ReferenceDatabase_2_name        CREATE TABLE `ReferenceDatabase_2_name` (
  `DB_ID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_rank` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  KEY `DB_ID` (`DB_ID`),
  KEY `name` (`name`(10))
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

Table   Create Table
ReferenceEntity CREATE TABLE `ReferenceEntity` (
  `DB_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `identifier` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `referenceDatabase` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `referenceDatabase_class` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`DB_ID`),
  KEY `referenceDatabase` (`referenceDatabase`),
  KEY `identifier` (`identifier`(10))
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

Table   Create Table
DatabaseObject  CREATE TABLE `DatabaseObject` (
  `DB_ID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `_class` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `_displayName` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_class` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `stableIdentifier` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `stableIdentifier_class` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`DB_ID`),
  KEY `_class` (`_class`),
  KEY `_timestamp` (`_timestamp`),
  KEY `created` (`created`),
  KEY `_displayName` (`_displayName`(10)),
  KEY `stableIdentifier` (`stableIdentifier`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=11631469 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

Table   Create Table
ReferenceSequence       CREATE TABLE `ReferenceSequence` (
  `DB_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `species` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `species_class` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `sequenceLength` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isSequenceChanged` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `checksum` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`DB_ID`),
  KEY `species` (`species`),
  KEY `sequenceLength` (`sequenceLength`),
  KEY `isSequenceChanged` (`isSequenceChanged`(10)),
  KEY `checksum` (`checksum`(10))
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

Table   Create Table
Species CREATE TABLE `Species` (
  `DB_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `abbreviation` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`DB_ID`),
  KEY `abbreviation` (`abbreviation`(10))
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

Table   Create Table
Taxon_2_name    CREATE TABLE `Taxon_2_name` (
  `DB_ID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_rank` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `DB_ID` (`DB_ID`),\n  KEY `name` (`name`)\n) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

SHOW CREATE TABLE from NEW server is identical to OLD server.

Comment: Please post SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; from OLD and NEW server for comparison analysis of GV OLD to NEW.  Also post your error log from the NEW server that includes data from the attempt to use the query described.  The query plans posted are now where similar in ROWS used by each part of the plan.

Comment: @WilsonHauck: Those are large dumps. Anything that can be safely filtered out?

Comment: @WilsonHauck: Trying to paste the FULL dump of global variables from both servers is exceeding the max content size. Do you have suggestions as to what I should filter for?

Comment: Please consider posting your results to pastebin.com and sharing the links and you will avoid the 'content size limit'.  Thanks,

Comment: Don't use so many derived tables.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` also.  How much RAM do you have?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Comment: @RickJames Both servers have 32 GB RAM, and MySQL usually has access to more than half. Will post links to data in pastbin soon...

Comment: @WilsonHauck: I got the global variables on pastbin. Ouptu from  `global status` and `show create table` to follow later...

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner Thanks for the Global Variables from 5.5.55 and 5.7.26.   Please also post your A) error log from the NEW server that includes data from the attempt to use the query described. B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; from each server and SHOW CREATE TABLE's from 5.7.26 used in the query (all of them) and SHOW INDEX FROM each table used in the query, please.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I've added the indices, global status, and CREATE TABLE statements. Logging is pretty minimal on this instance and I'm not sure I have the permission to update those settings, I'll have to look into that.

Comment: @RickJames: I've included the global status and create table statements.

Comment: There are 5 `MEDIUMTEXT` columns -- none sounds like it needs to be that big.  One even sounds like a yes/no flag.  This will let you get rid of the "prefix indexes", which are next to useless.  Switch to InnoDB; MyISAM is all but deprecated in 5.7.

Comment: @RickJames: The column types have been like that for longer than I've been on the project, and the data model is not something I generally have any control over. I'd love to drop MyISAM but that is not my decision to make, unfortunately. I can propose this again, and maybe failing queries will be a greater motivator this time.

Comment: I actually think they might counter-propose rolling back that server to 5.5 or 5.6... rather than switch to InnoDB.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner - Better to bite _these_ bullets _now_.  If you wait, 5.5 will be End-Of-Life'd and 8.0 (or whatever) will be even harder to upgrade to.

Comment: And, no, I don't know what caused the regression, but I do strongly suspect that Oracle would ignore any bug relating to MyISAM.  Meanwhile, _maybe_ my various suggestions will somehow avoid the regression.

Comment: @RickJames: I know this. The discussions to upgrade to 8.0 have been tentatively started, and will take a while before anything happens. In the meantime the quarterly process in which this query originates will be running *or failing* again in a couple of weeks. I need to figure out how to get the query working with what I've got *now*.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner - What _do they allow_ you to do?  Change indexes?  Change schema?  Rewrite query?  Try 5.6?  Avoid the query?  Write PHP code to do the equivalent?  Run the query on another machine?  Run it in stages?

Comment: @RickJames: Schema changes are out of my hands (schema is generated with some tool, upstream). My fall-back option is to implement this functionality with simpler queries, and Java to process their results into the same table. Not ideal, but it will work, if necessary. I could try rewriting the query, not sure if that will be easier than the Java route.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner - Assert yourself.  March up the chain until you can find someone who can make changes.  Meanwhile, warm up your resume; you seem to be trapped in a job without permission to achieve it.

Comment: @RickJames: Eh, it's not that bad. This database is almost "legacy" at this point and will probably be fully replaced soon (the replacement already exists and is in use in some environments). It's been in discussions for a while (probably since before I joined this team). This issue will probably motivate them to move a little faster, once I frame it right. But that will take longer than another quarterly cycle (or two), hence my need to get the query running. I'm sure you'll hear how that goes ;)

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner Please post TEXT results from Ubuntu Command prompt, ulimit -a so we can see your Open Files limit and other limits.  Do you use any of the Performance Schema data for analysis?  If NOT, turn PERFORMANCE SCHEMA OFF in my.cnf.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner Any SSD or NVME for data storage? Number of cores on CPU? Could you post COMPLETE results of MySQLTuner.pl (perl script)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, thanks to Rick James and Wilson Hauck who tried to help with this. It is greatly appreciated, and shows I still have much to learn in terms of fine-tuning MySQL databases.

I tried most of the suggestions above, alone and in combination, and so far, none of them have worked. :(

I did more research and happened upon a web page (lost the link, sorry) that described similar problems that I was having, with the `group_concat` function. I tried running the inner query with the `group_concat` as a stand-alone query, and found that when I removed the `group_concat`, I didn't have any problems! One suggestion on that other page was to change the `ORDER BY` of the query making use of `group_concat`. I noticed that I didn't *have* a sorting clause. I added one, and the query worked!! Query now looks more like this:

```
SELECT distinct subq1.duplicate_count, subq1.identifier, subq1.ReferenceEntity_DB_IDs, subq1._class AS object_type, subq1._displayName as display_name, subq1.combined_identifier, ReferenceDatabase_2_name.name as ref_db_name, subq1.species_db_id, subq1.species_name  
from ( 
    select count(ReferenceEntity.DB_ID) as duplicate_count, ReferenceEntity.identifier, group_concat(ReferenceEntity.db_id) as ReferenceEntity_DB_IDs, ReferenceEntity.referenceDatabase, DatabaseObject._class, DatabaseObject._displayName, subq.combined_identifier, subq.species_db_id, subq.species_name 
    from ReferenceEntity  
    inner join DatabaseObject on DatabaseObject.db_id = ReferenceEntity.db_id 
    inner join (select ReferenceEntity.*, concat(coalesce(ReferenceEntity.identifier,'NULL'),';', coalesce(DatabaseObject._displayName,'NULL')) as combined_identifier, species_subq.db_id AS species_db_id, species_subq.name AS species_name 
                from ReferenceEntity 
                inner join DatabaseObject on ReferenceEntity.db_id = DatabaseObject.db_id 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN ReferenceSequence ON ReferenceEntity.DB_ID = ReferenceSequence.DB_ID 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Species.DB_ID, Taxon_2_name.name 
                                   FROM Species  
                                   INNER JOIN Taxon_2_name ON (Taxon_2_name.DB_ID = Species.DB_ID AND Taxon_2_name.name_rank = 0)) AS species_subq 
               ON ReferenceSequence.species = species_subq.DB_ID 
                where ReferenceEntity.identifier is not null) as subq on subq.db_id = ReferenceEntity.db_id 
    group by subq.combined_identifier, ReferenceEntity.identifier, referenceDatabase, _class, _displayName, subq.species_db_id, subq.species_name 
    having count(ReferenceEntity.db_id) > 1
    -- The ORDER BY below is *NEW*
    order by ReferenceEntity.identifier desc ) as subq1 
inner join ReferenceDatabase_2_name on ReferenceDatabase_2_name.DB_ID = subq1.referenceDatabase 
where ReferenceDatabase_2_name.name_rank = 0 
order by duplicate_count, ReferenceDatabase_2_name.name, identifier;
```

So I guess for MySQL 5.7.26 (it seems someone upgraded recently), the results need to be sorted for group_concat.

What seems weird to me is that it seems to work with *any* sorting. I even tried `ORDER BY rand() desc` and the query ran just as well as when I specific an actual column name.

Now I'm wondering if there's a bug in MySQL `group_concat`...

Answer (score 1):

Ouch!

```
key_buffer_size 16777216
```

Set that to about 20% of *available* RAM.

```
join_buffer_size = 1M

tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size  -- about 1% of RAM
```

Note:  When (I'm not saying "if") you change to InnoDB, be sure to lower key_buffer_size down again, while raising innodb_buffer_pool_size to 70% of RAM.

(More after I review the VARIABLES and STATUS)

Check the engines -- none of the 5.5 is using InnoDB; some of 5.7 is.  Did *these* tables change when moving to 5.7??

For transitioning from MyISAM to InnoDB on a 32GB MySQL-only server:

```
key_buffer_size = 3G
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 10G
```

There are some nasty queries, both in the old system and new.

```
long_query_time = 1
```

and turn on the slowlog.  Then get help here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner - I added to my Answer.

Comment: I'll have a look at the engines. I did not do the initial setup. I suspect it was just a default installation, so if some defaults were InnoDB, maybe that's the problem and I need to switch them back to MyISAM... ? It's a lead, and I'm not sure I would have seen that myself. Thanks!

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner - Most important things for now is to change those two buffer sizes (and restart mysqld).  It is hard to predict how much it will help, and it is hard to predict whether some of the other "problems" will go away.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
max_heap_table_size=320M  # from 16M for ~ 1% RAM
tmp_table_size=320M  # from 16M for size matched to MHTSize
thread_cache_size=64  # from 8 to reduce threads_created count
sort_buffer_size=2M  # from 32M to conserve RAM requested per connection
slow_query_log=ON  # from OFF to allow daily monitoring
query_cache_size=0  # from 16M since Query_Cache_Type is OFF
lock_wait_timeout=300  # from 1 year of seconds, when REPLICATION not used
key_buffer_size=10G  # from 16M - all ISAM data tables
key_age_threshold=7200  # from 300 seconds to reduce key_reads
key_cache_block_size=16382  # from 1024 to reduce CPU cycles used for mgmt
key_cache_division_limit=50  # from 100 for HOT/WARM split to reduce key_reads
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to conserve CPU cycles every second for function
```

Disclaimer: I am the content author of web site listed in my profile, Network profile with contact information.

Answer (score 0):

A *possible* way to get 5.7 to optimize like 5.5 did for this one statement...

First take a look at

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'optimizer_switch';
```

You will set a lot of settings.  I think one of them controls a new feature that is not working well for your query.  I do not know if it is the only relevant one.  See if the `EXPLAIN` reverts when you do this:

```
SET SESSION optimizer_switch='materialization=off';
EXPLAIN SELECT ...
SET SESSION optimizer_switch='materialization=on';
```

If so, then add those `SETs` around your `SELECT`.

Comment: I tried this, the execution plan remained the same.